# How to create my grid of images into rows of 5

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this gallery break up into rows? right now it is one row of 8, but want to break it into half. How would I do that? so like 4 images to a row or 5? Thank you all :) below is a short example of the html and css had to tag beginning of the css like this for some reason. still fresh at programming.

**HTML**

```
<section id="Photos">            
    <div class="col-md-12 gallery">
        <h1>Gallery</h1>
        <ul id="photo-gallery">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="http://41.media.tumblr.com/0390d80d6c8cc4a7096033182a4bfe8a/tumblr_ndyvukSjNl1tubinno1_1280.jpg">
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>  
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
#Photos{
    opacity: .88
    padding: 0px
}
#Photos img{
    width: 10%
    float: left
    display: inline-block
    margin: 5px
    text-align: center
}
.gallery ul{
    list-style: none
    margin: auto
}
#overlay{
    background: rgba(0,0,0, .8)
    width: 100%
    height: 100%
    position: absolute
    top: 0
    left: 0
    display: none;
}
#overlay img{
    margin: 10% auto 0
    width: 550px
    border-radius: 5px
}
#photos{
    width: 100%
}
#photo-gallery{
    width: 100%
}
```

Comment: I think you are using Bootstrap, so I suggest you take a look at [Bootstrap grid examples](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fixed css to get what you want.

```
#Photos {
    opacity: .88;
}

.gallery ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.gallery img {
    width: 24%;
    margin: .5%;
    float: left;
}
```

Just keep in mind that ID selector (#) must be used once in a page, and if I was you, I'll rather consider using class for `#photo-gallery`.

*BTW, welcome on Stack Overflow!*